# Trouble with MYSQL insert and PHP quotations

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, quotes, double-quotes

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, password, email, phone, address)
VALUES ('$_POST['name']', '$_POST['password']', '$_POST['email']', '$_POST['phone']', '$_POST['address']', )";
```

As one can possibly see, I am trying to insert these values into my table; however I am getting an unexpected error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /home/csc4370FA14_18/public_html/program/assignments/group project3/register.php on line 35.

I assume it has something to do with the single quotations; is there a way to fix this with double quotes, backslash characters?

Comment: do you really need the trailing comma in your sql statement?

Answer (score 1):

Try assigning post values to new variable and then use the new variables in your sql statement. For example,

```
$name = $_POST['name'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO users ".
   "(name) ".
   "VALUES('$name')";
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your purpose.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, password, email, phone, address)
VALUES ('".$_POST['name']."', '".$_POST['password']."', '".$_POST['email']."', '".$_POST['phone']."', '".$_POST['address']."', )";
```

**Note**: I hope you are adding something after the last `,` in the query, otherwise this query will fail.